# How to align text into left inside the center environment?

Tags: vertical-alignment

[image]

I want to left align the font-awesome icons containing line alongside keeping these in center.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
 \LARGE{\textbf{To Learn \LaTeX{}}}
\\
\vspace{2cm}
 \faPhone{} 01515-611989\\
  \faEnvelope{} al2helal@gmail.com\\
  \faEnvelope{} alhelal@ieee.org\\
  \faHome{} Room - 1406, Extension-1, SH Hall
\\
\vspace{2cm}
Do you know what is \LaTeX{}?\\
  \LaTeX{} is a highly qualified and powerfull document preparation system \& software.
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `tabular`. It'll be centered because of the `center` environment, but its contents will be left aligned:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
{\LARGE\textbf{To Learn \LaTeX{}}}

\vspace{2cm}
\begin{tabular}{l}
  \faPhone{} 01515-611989\\
  \faEnvelope{} al2helal@gmail.com\\
  \faEnvelope{} alhelal@ieee.org\\
  \faHome{} Room - 1406, Extension-1, SH Hall
\end{tabular}

\vspace{2cm}
Do you know what is \LaTeX{}?

\LaTeX{} is a highly qualified and powerfull document preparation system \& software.
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `tabular`. Beware that `\LARGE` is not a command with argument, but a declaration.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\vspace*{\fill}

\begin{center}
 {\LARGE\textbf{To Learn \LaTeX{}}}
\\[2cm]
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
\faPhone    & 01515-611989\\
\faEnvelope & al2helal@gmail.com\\
\faEnvelope & alhelal@ieee.org\\
\faHome     & Room - 1406, Extension-1, SH Hall
\end{tabular}
\\[2cm]
Do you know what is \LaTeX{}?

\LaTeX{} is a highly qualified and powerful document 
preparation system \& software.
\end{center}

\vspace*{\fill}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the desired look, either

Stack it!...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
 \LARGE{\textbf{To Learn \LaTeX{}}}
\\
\vspace{2cm}
\Longstack[l]{
 \faPhone{} 01515-611989\\
  \faEnvelope{} al2helal@gmail.com\\
  \faEnvelope{} alhelal@ieee.org\\
  \faHome{} Room - 1406, Extension-1, SH Hall
  }
\\
\vspace{2cm}
Do you know what is \LaTeX{}?\\
  \LaTeX{} is a highly qualified and powerfull document preparation system \& software.
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

or TABStack it!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstacktabbedgap{1ex}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
 \LARGE{\textbf{To Learn \LaTeX{}}}
\\
\vspace{2cm}
\tabbedLongstack{
 \faPhone{}& 01515-611989\\
  \faEnvelope{}&al2helal@gmail.com\\
  \faEnvelope{}&alhelal@ieee.org\\
  \faHome{}&Room - 1406, Extension-1, SH Hall
  }
\\
\vspace{2cm}
Do you know what is \LaTeX{}?\\
  \LaTeX{} is a highly qualified and powerfull document preparation system \& software.
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your first option's output looks similar of @Phelype Oleinik but in different way.